# A quotient topological space that isn't Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, group-actions, quotient-spaces

Consider the group action $G=\mathbb{Z}$ on $X=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ given by $n \cdot (x,y)=(2^nx,2^{-n}y)$. How to prove that $X/G$ isn't a Hausdorff space? I tried by searching 2 points in the quotient that are not "separated" by 2 open disjointed sets, but this seems to go nowhere. What can I do?

Comment: Take (x,0), (0,y) with $x,y \neq 0$ they have other representative as close as you wish to 0.

Comment: That doesn't help much. You can have an open ball around each $(x,0), x \neq 0$ with radius $0.1x$, and that open ball will be completely below the $x=y$ line. You can also have an open ball around each $(0,y), y \neq 0$ with radius $0.1y$, and that open ball will be completely above the $x=y$ line. So none of the balls around any $(x,0)$ will intersect any of the balls around $(0,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stumped me for a bit as well, but ... have you considered the orbits of $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$?

Comment: If you are only thinking like the comment by Matias Matteini, that isn't enough. You also have to consider the neighborhoods around those orbits.